# exchange user name, forward address, and account status

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server

I am trying to export a list of users from the exchange powershell, with their forwarding address, and whether or not the account is disabled or enabled. I am having to use two commands and manually copy each forwarding address to each user in the AD spreadsheet. Is there a way to merge these commands into one so I do not have to do any manual work on it aside from deleting a single column showing the ou path (would be nice if it wasn't included in the first place)?

Exchange script:

```
$fwds = get-mailbox -organizationalunit "OU=25 - Preferred Bank,OU=Hosted Exchange Customers,DC=DMZ,DC=local" -resultsize unlimited | Where-Object { $_.ForwardingAddress -ne $null } | sort Name | select Name, ForwardingAddress

foreach ($fwd in $fwds) {$fwd | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name "ContactAddress" -value (get-Recipient $fwd.ForwardingAddress).PrimarySmtpAddress}

$fwds | Export-Csv c:\Users\x\Desktop\forwards.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

AD script:

```
get-aduser -searchbase "OU=25 - Preferred Bank,OU=Hosted Exchange Customers,DC=DMZ,DC=local" | select name,enabled
```

Nick when adding the -expand it gives the following:

```
Select-Object : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "obj" is null. Change the value of argument "obj"
 to a non-null value.
At C:\Users\x\Desktop\try_2.ps1:9 char:59
+ $fwd = get-mailbox -Identity $user.samaccountname | select <<<<  -expand ForwardingAddress
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], PSArgumentNullException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNull,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I got this working finally. I think my problem may have been I was using exchange powershell with ad module loaded and not just powershell with the exchange and ad modules loaded.

```
#Get users
$users = get-aduser -searchbase "OU=ou,OU=Hosted Exchange Customers,DC=DMZ,DC=local" -Filter * | select samaccountname, name, enabled

#Loop through users to get info
$output = foreach ($user in $users)
{
    #Get the forwarding address on the mailbox
    $fwd = (get-mailbox -Identity $user.samaccountname -ErrorAction silentlycontinue).forwardingaddress

    if($fwd)
    {
    #Get the SMTP of the forwarding address if it exists
    $PrimarySMTP =  (get-Recipient $fwd).PrimarySMTPAddress
    }
    else{$PrimarySMTP = ""}

    #Create custom object to export CSV with all info.
    New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
        User= $User.Name
        Enabled = $user.Enabled
        ForwardingAddress= $PrimarySMTP}
}

#$output

$output | Export-Csv "C:\users\%username%\desktop\25_quarterly_report.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: You should never post an answer to your own question when trying to edit, you should edit your own post. That's not working because you didn't do `select -expand forwardingaddress`

Comment: @Nick Sorry, I added what happens when I add the -expand tag to it, to the OP.

Comment: Try changing it to this: `(get-mailbox -Identity $user.samaccountname).forwardingaddress`

Comment: @nick I did that, and it gave a few errors, but it returned the primary email address for the users, not the forwarded address. Ive been playing around with it and its either giving me that, or no addresses. 

It keep complaining about not being able to convert a system string to a script block. and its still pointing to line 9 ops 59, the select statement.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
#Get users
$users = get-aduser -searchbase "OU=25 - Preferred Bank,OU=Hosted Exchange Customers,DC=DMZ,DC=local" | select samaccountname, name,enabled

#Loop through users to get info
foreach ($user in $users)
{

#Get the forwarding address on the mailbox
$fwd = get-mailbox -Identity $user.samaccountname | select -expand ForwardingAddress
if($fwd)
{ 

#Get the SMTP of the forwarding address if it exists
$PrimarySMTP =  (get-Recipient $fwd | select  PrimarySMTPAddress).PrimarySMTPAddress
}
else{$PrimarySMTP = ""}

#Create custom object to export CSV with all info.
    New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
                User= $User.Name
                Enabled = $user.Enabled
                ForwardingAddress= $PrimarySMTP}  | Export-Csv c:\Users\x\Desktop\forwards.csv -NoTypeInformation -append
    }
```

Comment: I attempted to use this, and I am getting a few errors I will amend them to the OP.